# How to validate int and boolean with sequelize and sqlite

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, typescript, sequelize.js

I have a node application which is written in typescript, uses sqlite database and I want to have model validation with sequelize. Only something is working though.

For example:

```
@AllowNull(false)
@IsInt
@Length({min: 4, max: 4})
@Column
seasonFrom: number
```

Here the length validation work but @IsInt does not. If I have a string value there, the string value is saved to the db, no error has been thrown.
I have tried to use this:

```
@Column(DataType.INTEGER)
```

but the same situation.

I also want to validate some string and boolean values but I do not see any method like @IsString or @IsBoolean.

Answer (score 1):

in the model definition you can specify your own validators as functions like this for each column  :

```
          // in the column definition 
          const model = sequelize.define('Model', {
             numberColumn :{
                allowNull:false,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                validate: {
                isNumber: function (val) {
                      // here you can use any method to determine if it's a 
                         number or not 
                      if (typeof val == "number") { return 
                             return Number.isInteger(val);
                             }else{ return false; }
                  }

                },
             boolenColumn: {
                      type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
                      validate: { 
                        // you can add here any  validation you want 
                         isBoolean:function (val) {
                              return (typeof(val)=='boolean')
                                 }
                }
           }
```

Comment: seems like the way to define custom validators have went through some changes, be sure to check the docs https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/upgrade-to-v5.html